# nqueen without backtracking

Tags: algorithm

Can the **n queen** problem be solved without backtracking?

I have met with many types of answers to the **n queen** problem but all of them require backtracking. Is there a way of solving it without backtracking?

Comment: YOU COULD WITHOUT BRUTE FORCING I HAVE THE ANSWER

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING, AND IF YOU HAVE THE ANSWER WHY ARE YOU ASKING?

Comment: it is the way of sharing the knowledge after giving everybody a try

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You could brute-force it by generating all possible boards, and then testing each.

This approach would not scale well though ;)

Please also note that the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Exercise_in_algorithm_design) lists a number of solutions, including "iterative repair".

Comment: iterative repair is least effecient

Comment: @akhil I'm pretty sure brute-force is less efficient!

Answer (score 1):

A genetic algorithm that evolves the best solution wouldn't require backtracking, but that is a different way of approaching the problem than an algorithm to traverse the state space graph which your question seems to imply

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Wikipedia mentions a few, including one based off determinants (which I'm curious about now, but have not tracked down).  Let me copy-paste one [verbatim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Explicit_solutions):

> The examples above can be obtained with the following formulas. Let (i, j) be the square in column i and row j on the n × n chessboard, k an integer.

1. If n is even and n ≠ 6k + 2, then place queens at (i, 2i) and (n/2 +
   i, 2i - 1) for i = 1,2,...,n/2.
2. If n is even and n ≠ 6k, then place queens at (i, 1 + (2i + n/2 - 3 (mod n))) and (n + 1 - i, n - (2i + n/2 - 3 (mod n))) for i = 1,2,...,n/2.
3. If n is odd, then use one of the patterns above for (n - 1) and add a queen at (n, n).